# Pass variable to href template in Django 2

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have below function in my views.py Django 2 project and I am trying to pass the variable "stylefolder" from views.py to my base.html template in order to dynamically get the correct href in my link tag.

Below is my current code:

```
def home(request):
  products = Product.objects.order_by('-votes_total')
  paginator = Paginator(products, 10)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)

  context = {
    'products':paged_listings,
    'stylefolder': 'cryptoblog/style.css'
  }
  return render(request,'home1.html', context)
```

In the base.html file, I have below code.

```
href="{% static '{{ stylefolder }}' %}">
```

The problem is that when I look into the view:Source section of the page, I get as a result:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/%7B%7B%20stylefolder%20%7D%7D">
```

Instead of below desired result:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/cryptoblog/style.css">
```

What should I change to get "/static/cryptoblog/style.css" in the href tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in a *template tag*, you should not add the double curly brackets `{{ .. }}`, you can use the variablename instead, like:

```
<link href="{% static stylefolder %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"">
```

The reason why you get `/static/%7B%7B%20stylefolder%20%7D%7D` is because this is the [*percent-encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of the `'{{ stylefolder }}'` string. This is logical, since it looks like you passed a string *literal*:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('/static/%7B%7B%20stylefolder%20%7D%7D')
'/static/{{ stylefolder }}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do: 
`href="/static/{{ stylefolder }}">`

Comment: But this would not show the `/static` (or where the static files are served).